# How to use global class object reference across the modules..?

Tags: python, class, import, pycharm, global-variables

config.py

```py
c=None
```

myfirst.py

```py
import second
import config

class b:
    def __init__(self):
        config.c=second.c()
```

second.py

```py
import config

class c:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hy")
```

third.py

```py
import myfirst
import config
class s:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=myfirst.b()
        self.a.config.c  ##want to use this statement but it giving following error
s()
```

`AttributeError: 'b' object has no attribute 'config'`

Is there any other way to use class object ref across module?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: can you please take a look into the error,,as i am getting only this error..

Comment: Your `b.__init__` is just setting a variable in the `config` module.  That module is not a part of `b`.  Note that you don't need `self.a.config.c`.  You have imported `config`, so you can just refer to `config.c` in ANY module that imports `config`.